# is there function to print all the roads inside the tree

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw663.png)[2]suppose we have the tree shown in the photo..
I didn't find function that can tell all the roads inside the tree ..
I just want function or algorithms that can print all the roads
I am trying hard to find
a function that can print all the roads inside the tree:
for the case here , the result should be like this :

```
 1->2->4->8->16
    1->2->4->8->17
    1->2->4->8->16
    1->2->4->9->18
    1->2->4->9->19
    1->2->5->10->20
    1->2->5->10->21
    1->2->5->11->22
    1->2->5->11->23
    1->3->6->12->24
    1->3->6->12->25
    1->3->6->13->26
    1->3->6->13->27
    1->3->7->14->28
    1->3->7->14->29
    1->3->7->15->30
    1->3->7->15->31
```

Comment: The function you are asking for will depend on how your tree is implemented. How is it implemented in your case? Can you provide the code that builds the tree you have shown? Also, your question is confusing. You speak of "function that can **count** all the roads" and you speak of "function that can **print** all the roads". Which of the two is it?

Comment: I already edit the post ..function can print all the roads

Comment: What is the correspondence between `{A,B,C,...}` and `{0,1,2,...}`? Is it rooted [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) you are looking for?

Comment: please can see the photo now I  updated again  ..it is not matter how the tree looks like , i just want a function can print all the roads inside the tree ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

One might use depth-first-search to solve this, where *roads* are edges. Adapted from [Wikipedia's DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) pseudo-code, where `v` is the vertex labelled 1, (the root.)

```
procedure DFS(G, v, S) is
    label v as discovered
    S.push(v)
    leaf := true
    for all directed edges from v to w that are in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
        if vertex w is not labelled as discovered then
            leaf := false
            DFS(G, w, S)
    if leaf
        output S
    S.pop()
```

Where `S` is an initially empty stack. I modified the recursive DFS algorithm to keep track of the nodes visited in `S`; the `output S` is called every time it gets to a leaf, (or a dead-end, in the case of non-tree graphs.) Because it's a tree, an acyclic graph, the `discovered` is unnecessary if you have a digraph whose edges only go one way.